# Lightning-combobox added inside a <div> with fixed height and overflow-y looses focus in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a `<lightning-combobox>` which I placed inside a `<div>` with fixed height. Now since the outer `<div>` has fixed height and if my dropdown is long then it is not showing all values, so I added a fixed height to my combobox and added `overflow-y:auto.` This is showing a scrolbar to my combobox but when trying to scroll it looses focus.

HTML:

```
<div style="height:44vh;overflow-y:auto;width:90%;padding-left: 9%;">
    <div style="width:200px;margin-top:10px;">Heading</div>
    <div class="slds-box slds-box_small" style="height:270px;">
      <div style="height:24vh;overflow-y:auto;">
          <lightning-combobox name="Select an option" variant="label-hidden" placeholder="Select an option" value={selectedYear} options={alloptions} onchange={handleYearChange}></lightning-combobox>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I'm not adding height on combobox and jus adding `style="overflow:visible"` its looking like this:
[image]

The second case looks fine for me but when i'm trying to scroll the combobox it looses focus. Tried, Z-index, overflow:initial, overflow:visible but nothing is working. Can someone let me know if I'm missing anything here

If I'm adding height on combobox its looking like this:

[image]